# jQuery slider not working (bxSlider)

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I can't seem to make the bxSlider working properly and can't find the reason why.

This is my code

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Maxime G - Home</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="keywords" content="portfolio ,html, css, c#, wordpress, UK, developer, front-end, back-end, programming, freelancer, freelance, maxime, godrie, maxime godrie, website" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" />

<script src="/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.1-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="/js/slider/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    });
</script>
```

```
<section class="sectionCarouselIndex">
     <ul class="bxslider">                                
         <li><img src="img/c2c.jpg" /></li>
         <li><img src="img/dcs-full.jpg" /></li>
         <li><img src="img/eding.jpg" /></li>
         <li><img src="img/karim-full.jpg" /></li>        
         <li><img src="img/waterside-full.jpg" /></li>
         <li><img src="img/chesil-full.jpg" /></li>
         <li><img src="img/enw-full.jpg"/></li>
         <li><img src="img/drl-full.jpg" /></li>   
         <li><img src="img/portal-full.jpg" /></li>
         <li><img src="img/comixology-full.png" /></li>
         <li><img src="img/history-full.jpg" /></li>
         <li><img src="img/parkmap-full.png" /></li>
     </ul>
</section>
```

This is the error I am getting in the Firefox console:

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

[Break On This Error]   

$(document).ready(function () {

index.html (line 25)

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

$(document).ready(function () {
```

If you want to have a look It actually looks like it's working there, but on my local machine there is no way I can make this slider work properly.

Comment: What happens when you take out modernizr?

Comment: What does the browser error log in the web console say ?

Comment: @Crowjonah it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I had the same problem. It was just about permissions. The CSS and bxslider script weren't being loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the jquery min script reference before the bxslider.js

Replace this

```
<script src="/js/slider/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

With

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="/js/slider/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Demipouce, but jquery min file must be at top. Also could you provide any demo for your page?

Comment: I just edited my question to show you what error I am getting

Comment: If you are use prototype load jquery.bxslider.js before jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: You are saviour buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                        autoControls: true
                    });
            });
</script>
```

Try this one as you are not providing any method.

Answer (score 1):

I just had bxslider stop working in a Wordpress theme i'm using.  Wordpress 3.4.2 uses jquery1.7.2, Wordpress 3.5 uses jquery1.8.3.  When i drop the jquery1.7.2 file back in there, bxslider works again.  Looks like whatever changed between 1.7.2 and 1.8.0 in jquery broke bxslider.

Answer (score -1):

I found I need to be more specific that than the document originally lets on probably due to changes in the spec I found this code works better:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slider/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
```